# Ordering the SQL where conditions so that the most commonly true is first

Tags: sql, oracle

Considering that you have a query like the one bellow and have several thousand records to process:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE A.COLUMN IN (some list) OR VARIABLE='SOMETHING'
```

I have confidence that in most cases `VARIABLE='SOMETHING'` will be true, do you think that switching the where condition to

```
WHERE VARIABLE='SOMETHING' OR A.COLUMN IN (some list)
```

making the mostly true (and clearly lighter on the processing requirements) condition first give a nice boost in performance? I don't have a dataset in development big enough to test this for myself

Comment: In any case, it is hard to see what would be the downside of doing so. At best you get a nice boost in performance and at worst (if the optimizer can somehow figure that out for you and make the change internally) you are just making life easier for the optimizer.

Comment: Have you tried running an explain plan against both scenarios and reviewing if one comes out with a higher cost?

Comment: In the old, old days when Oracle used a rule-based optimizer, the order of conditions was significant (but IIRC it worked from the last condition backwards!).  Since Oracle 7 (or maybe 8) it has had a cost-based optimizer, which is not influenced by the order of the conditions.

Comment: And even if it did work, the IN condition is according to you more selective, and so it might be better to process that first - find the small number of records that meet that condition and then only perform the SOMETHING test a small number of times.  But it won't work...

Comment: @dvsoukup I didn't even knew that tool in Oracle (I come from SQLServer and I'm not much of a DB guy)

Comment: @JSantos Yeah it's pretty simple to run.  First I'd google what the explain plan is.  Nut-shell version is that it tells you how Oracle arrived at the results and what the cost of that path was, amongst other things.  Can be done with:   EXPLAIN PLAN FOR <enter your SELECT query here...>

Comment: @TonyAndrews the're mutually exclusive (I think that's how you say it in english) meaning that only one of them will return results. If VARIABLE='SOMETHING' is true, it will return all results and A.COLUMN IN (some list) is actually 0 results since the list is empty. But considering what you said it's irrelevant the order so I should just focus somewhere else when optimizing it right?

Comment: @dvsoukup forgot to mention it's a procedure (just tagged it now). I will try to extract the relevant queries and check how they perform

Comment: Yes, look at query plans and consider what indexes might be useful - e.g. an index on A.COLUMN.  You could put an index on A.VARIABLE but if you expect that to be 'SOMETHING' on most rows then the optimizer probably wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with more performance question, you should test the two versions.  However, unless the list is rather long, then this probably will not make a difference in performance.

You can try adding indexes, particularly on `A(column)` and `A(variable, column)`.  Oracle is smart in its use of indexes, but it might not be quite smart enough in this case (you need to look at the execution plans).  You could rephrase the query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE VARIABLE = 'SOMETHING'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE A.COLUMN IN (some list) AND VARIABLE <> 'SOMETHING';
```

Oracle should use both indexes in this case.

Comment: That's a nice way of writing it even though it will turn a big procedure into a bigger one (in terms of code)